# SecurityException while opening provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Basically, I am trying to import a contact VCard shared via Google text messenger.From A RequestPermissions Activity 'B'(B is a Util class) will be called from an activity A. Before B gets launched I am finishing A and passing A's intent to B. After permissions accepted/denied in B, I am relaunching Activity A. The problem is I am getting Exception as

Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.messaging.shared.datamodel.MediaScratchFileProvider from ProcessRecord{1dd630a 12643:com.example.sample/u0a127} (pid=12643, uid=10127) that is not exported from uid 10077

I tried several answers and I am unable to solve the problem. According to the documentation, Uri permissions last until its activity instance finishes. I think finishing my activity A causing permission denial even though permissions are accepted, but the requirement is Activity A has to be finished and relaunched. Please provide your suggestions to solve the issue.

Comment: You would have to pass the `Uri` along in the `Intent` objects and include `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`, to pass along the read access rights.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. The scenario is Go from A to B, finish A and do something in B and relaunch A using its intent passed to B. I requested READ_CONTACTS and READ_STORAGE permissions to A. So i finished A and try to extract the Uri content I am having the exception. While relaunching A from B i gave setData(uri), addFlags() as u specified but its not working. getting another exception as "java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10096 does not have permission to uri 0 @content://com.google. android.apps.messaging.shared.datamodel.MediaScratchFileProvider/4913931653050365013". Please help.